# Steps to include float_pkg to a synthesizable VHDL project

Tags: floating-point, package, vhdl, fpga, synthesis

I used in my VHDL emulator float64 (double precision floating point) data type by calling the floating point package depending on the emulator vendor (Altera or Xilinx..):

```
library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.float_pkg.all;
```

or

```
library ieee;
use ieee.float_pkg.all;
```

I want now to download the VHDL design to an FPGA board (mainly Xilinx Virtex 6). I think that this package is not supported by the FPGA.

I found an answer in the following link: [Answer for including float-pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154202/cant-include-float-pkg-into-project) 
I downloaded the following backwards-compatible approximated version:
[float package here](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/)

I have the following questions: 
- Now having downloaded this approximated package, how to include it in my VHDL working directory where my synthesizable code resides and is this downloaded package compatible with Xilinx (or Altera)? In other words, what are the detailed steps to compile (and call) this backwards-compatible approximated version in my ISE design suite 14.7 or Vivado (for Xilinx) since I have a Xilinx board or worst case in Quartus prime (Altera) if I should purchase an intel board?
- If this downloaded backward-compatible approximation package is not compatible is there another one I can download? 
- Lastly, is there an FPGA board that supports VHDL double floating point data type on the market?

Comment: Or just turn on VHDL-2008, where these packages have been moved into the IEEE library. Any FPGA can support these packages : if support is missing, that's the synthesis tool's fault not the FPGA.

Comment: I think the problem is solved. I used under ISE design tool the IEEE.proposed.float.pkg  and I had no problem in the synthesis using Virtex 6 target FPGA.